# united authentication for multiple *nix hosts?

Tags: domain, unix, authentication, users

Something similar to NT domain controller in Linux?

E.g. two hosts with one shared authentication.

How to?

Answer (score 4):

There's [NIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service).
There's LDAP ([pam_ldap](http://oss.sgi.com/LDP/HOWTO/LDAP-Implementation-HOWTO/pamnss.html), [nss-pam-ldapd](http://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/) - this can auth against AD too!).
There's various flavors of [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) (though I've always found setup annoying).
There's [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) (for authenticating to Windows/AD directly).
There's a bunch of other options.

Pick one, and google for a howto.  There are plenty out there.

There's also **doing some research before you ask a question** (which is why I downvoted this question).

Answer (score 2):

Is Google broken??

LDAP is what you're after... on Linux I'll believe you'll use OpenLDAP. There is plenty of material available for setting this on a number of different distributions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol

All the information you need is there, and in the documentation for the various different Linux distrbutions.

Comment: [http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/google.com](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/google.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use Active Directory/LDAP for that. Basic google search for active directory integration with linux will shield lot of results. Here is a basic guide:
http://rjalan.blogspot.com/2008/03/ubuntu-710-server-and-active-directory.html

LDAP/NIS would also work.